# Why aren't these two properties of complex powers the same?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $z\in\mathbb{C}$ s.t. $z=u+iv$. As an example, take the square in this trivial manner: $(u+iv)^2=u^2-v^2+2iuv$.  On the other hand taking the square using the properties of complex powers, i.e. 
\begin{align*}
(u+iv)^2&=e^{2[\log(u+iv)+2\pi ni]} \\
&=e^{2\log\left(\sqrt{u^2+v^2}\right)+2i\theta +4\pi ni} \\
&=(u^2+v^2)e^{2i\theta} \\
&=(u^2+v^2)(\cos(2\theta)+i\sin(2\theta))
\end{align*}

That's as far as I can get to. I also tried solving for $\theta$ by setting the equations equal to each other but that didn't get me anywhere, this is where I left it as $\frac{2iuv}{u^2-v^2}=\tan(2\theta)$. So my question is, are these two properties of powers supposed to be the same?

Answer (score 1):

yes they are the same. In fact in the first case you are writing $(u+iv)^2$ in terms of real and imaginary parts but in the second case you are writing $(u+iv)^2$ in terms of magnitude and phase. because $|u^2-v^2+2iuv|=\sqrt {(u^2-v^2)^2+(2uv)^2}=u^2+v^2$

each complex number can be written in two forms:
real and imaginary elements:   $a+ib$
polar form                 :   $ce^{i\theta}$
which we have: $c=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and $tan(\theta)=\frac{b}{a}$
here we have: $u^2+v^2=\sqrt{(u^2+v^2)^2+(2uv)^2}$ and $tan(2\theta)=\frac{2uv}{u^2-v^2}$

Comment: Thanks! that really cleared things up

Answer (score 0):

Hint: In order to show that two complex numbers $z_1,z_2$ are equal it is enough to show that $|z_1|=|z_2|$ and that they create the same angel with the real axes.

Comment: IMO all complex numbers are *angelic* within the $z$-plane :-)